# Hibernate Mysql Testdatabase engine[*]=InnoDB; expected "identifier"

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, kotlin

I am trying myself with Spring Boot using a Mysql Database. At the moment I am trying to test my project and I am encountering the following Problem:

I want to set up my table using schema.sql which looks like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ausgaben` (
  ID TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  AMOUNT INT DEFAULT NULL,
  PLACE VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  DATUM DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  CATEGORY varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  primary key (ID)
);
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=testuser
spring.datasource.password=passwort

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

My Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Ausgaben")
data class AusgabeEntity(
        @Id
        val id: Timestamp,
        val amount: Double,
        val place: String,
        val datum: LocalDate,
        val category: String
)
```

My Test looks like this:

```
@Test
    fun `post method creates an Ausgabe-Entity in Repository`(){
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, ausgabeRepository.count())

        logger.info(ausgabeRepository.count().toString())

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/save?amount=10&place=lidl&category=haushalt"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)

        Assertions.assertEquals(1, ausgabeRepository.count())

        logger.info(ausgabeRepository.count().toString())
        logger.info(ausgabeRepository.findAll().toString())
    }
```

The Test works, but in the Stacktrace it says while executing my schema.sql:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table ausgaben (id datetime(6) not null, amount float(53) not null, category varchar(255), datum date, place varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC [Syntax Fehler in SQL Befehl "create table ausgaben (id datetime(6) not null, amount float(53) not null, category varchar(255), datum date, place varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine[*]=InnoDB"; erwartet "identifier"
Syntax error in SQL statement "create table ausgaben (id datetime(6) not null, amount float(53) not null, category varchar(255), datum date, place varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine[*]=InnoDB"; expected "identifier";]
```

So it looks like spring appends "engine=InnoDB" to my table definition and then can't read it?

Can someone explain, what happens here?

Thanks for your help

When i am altering the schema.sql to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ausgaben` (
  ID TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  AMOUNT INT DEFAULT NULL,
  FAILURE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PLACE VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  DATUM DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  CATEGORY varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  primary key (ID)
);
```

I can see, that the Test fails with

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [NULL nicht zulässig für Feld "FAILURE"
NULL not allowed for column "FAILURE"; SQL statement:
insert into ausgaben (amount,category,datum,place,id) values (?,?,?,?,?) [23502-224]] [insert into ausgaben (amount,category,datum,place,id) values (?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into ausgaben (amount,category,datum,place,id) values (?,?,?,?,?)]; constraint [null]
```

So it seems, as if it actually does build the table. So I don't understand why it throws Syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect** for spring.jpa.database-platform